# proving that If $F$ is countable, then $F$ may or may not be closed

Tags: general-topology

In my general topology textbook there is the following exercise:

> If $F$ is a non-empty countable subset of $\mathbb R$, prove that $F$ is not an open set, but that $F$ may or may not but a closed set depending on the choice of $F$.

I already proved that $F$ is not opened in the euclidean topology, but why is the second part true?

If $F$ is countable then $F \sim \mathbb N$. This means that we can list the elements of $F$, so we can write: $F=\{f_1,...,f_k,...\}$

$\mathbb R \setminus F= (-\infty, f_1) \cup \bigcup \limits _{i=1}^{\infty}(f_i,f_{i + 1})$

We have that $(-\infty, f_1) \in \tau$ and that every $(f_i,f_{i + 1}) \in \tau$. Because the union of elements of $\tau$ is also a element of $\tau$, we have that $(-\infty, f_1) \cup \bigcup \limits _{i=1}^{\infty}(f_i,f_{i + 1}) \in \tau$, then $F$ is closed.

Is this correct, because the statement says that "may or may not but a closed set depending on the choice of $F$"?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  $\mathbb N$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.  $\mathbb Q$ is not closed in $\mathbb R$.  And, of course, both $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ are countable.   Does that answer your question?

Comment: But then why is my proof wrong?

Comment: I don't understand what statement you are proving.  Can you state it clearly?

Comment: More broadly, your argument makes no sense.  You appear to be asserting that every countable subset of $\mathbb R$ has a least element, which you call $f_1$.  But of course this is not true.

Comment: If $F$ is closed then $\mathbb R \setminus F \in \tau$, and $\mathbb R \setminus F = (-\infty, f_1) \cup \bigcup \limits _{i=1}^{\infty}(f_i,f_{i + 1})$. Every $(f_i,f_{i + 1}) \in \tau$ and $(-\infty, f_1) \in \tau$ so $\mathbb R \setminus F \in tau$, thus $F$ is closed

Comment: So your claim is that "If $F$ is closed then $F$ is closed"?

Comment: No. the exercise stated that "$F$ may or may not but a closed set depending on the choice of $F$". And I proved that $F$ is always closed, and I'm trying to find the mistake in the proof.

Comment: The argument in your comment starts with the assumption that $F$ is closed, so I don't see the point you are making.  In any case:  you have been handed a couple of counterexamples to the claim that "countable $\implies$ closed".  I proposed $\mathbb Q$, somebody else proposed $\{\frac 1n\}$.  Take either of these sets and try to apply your argument to it and I expect you'll see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are supposing that you can write $F=\{f_1,f_2,\ldots\}$  where the $f_i$'s are in increasing order in $\mathbb{R}.$ This isn't true, for example consider $\mathbb Z\subset\mathbb R$. However, this is still closed. If you want a countable set which is not closed, you should consider a sequence approaching a given point, say the set $\{\frac{1}{n}\;|\;n\in\mathbb N\}$. Can you show that this isn't closed?

Answer (score 0):

Finite unions of closed sets are closed, but infinite unions need not be.  Look for a set of points that approaches a limit.  If that limit is not in the set, the set is not closed.

Comment: yes but infinite unions of open sets are opened

Comment: That is true, but irrelevant for this question.  It gives us that infinite intersections of closed sets are closed, which is true.  All the points are closed sets, but you do not necessarily have that a countable union of points is closed.

Answer (score 0):

A countably large set consisting of the points in this sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n}$ is not closed. It does not contain the limit point $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well $\Bbb Z$ is countable and closed, and $\Bbb Q$ is countable and not closed (even dense). So both are possible for countable sets. All that wass asked essentially is two examples.